# Elastic Search query_shard_exception failed to execute query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want search URL partially and I am using the following query:

```
GET test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "*http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/blt5ed2da305d61b2a2/blt10e8f794fa8597d0/5c481035fecde97033721922b/Screenshot_from_2018-07-30_09-53-42.png*",
                    "fields": ["url"],
                    "default_operator": "OR"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "query_shard_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to parse query [*http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/blt5ed2da305d61b2a2/blt10e8f794fa8597d0/5c481035fecde97033721922/Screenshot_from_2018-07-30_09-53-42.png*]",
            "index_uuid": "ytCEFbRQSmOaIaCXA5Q7LQ",
            "index": "test"
        }],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [{
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "test",
            "node": "EVRoeO0DTIOQKf95TeA_7g",
            "reason": {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "Failed to parse query [*http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/blt5ed2da305d61b2a2/blt10e8f794fa8597d0/5c481035fecde97033721922/Screenshot_from_2018-07-30_09-53-42.png*]",
                "index_uuid": "ytCEFbRQSmOaIaCXA5Q7LQ",
                "index": "test",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "parse_exception",
                    "reason": "Cannot parse '*http://localhost:8000/v3/assets/blt5ed2da305d61b2a2/blt10e8f794fa8597d0/5c481035fecde97033721922/Screenshot_from_2018-07-30_09-53-42.png*': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <EOF> \n    <AND> ...\n    <OR> ...\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"^\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    ",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "parse_exception",
                        "reason": "Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <EOF> \n    <AND> ...\n    <OR> ...\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"^\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    "
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong here? I am using query_string to search for the URL but getting above error with status 400.
Please help me into this.

Answer (score 3):

In the [query string query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), there are some [reserved characters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters), namely `:` and `/` which you need to escape, like this:

```
    "query": "*http\\:\\/\\/localhost\\:8000\\/v3\\/assets\\/blt5ed2da305d61b2a2\\/blt10e8f794fa8597d0\\/5c481035fecde97033721922b\\/Screenshot_from_2018-07-30_09-53-42.png*"
```